# Heartbeat protocol

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have a client/server FTP application and I want to implement a heartbeat protocol to check the connections. It occurred to me that if I use the same output and input streams that my client and server are using to send and receive files, I'm going to encounter some problems. I don't think I can't open up multiple streams (unless of they're of different types like DataOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream). Is there a way around this particular issue? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you trying to monitor the connection from, client or server?

Comment: From the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're trying to do, receive a same stream in two places, isn't possible.  The closest thing to that would be reverse proxying the stream, so you run a reverse proxy, the client connects to the proxy service (running on the server) and the proxy connects to the original service.

In that fashion the proxy should be able to monitor the connections.

Another alternative, if you can is to run an 'admin service' on the server's FTP application.  So modify the ftp server to open another port that you connect to, to get admin info, such as connection health.

The first solution is probably more work but is possible if you don't have access to the ftp app. source code.  And vice-versa.

Comment: I see. So essentially open up another ServerSocket on a different port and report all the health info to that one?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.